# magento get bundled product if from its product id

Tags: product, bundled-product

i want to get bundled product id made using product ids.

suppose there is bundled product A made using product B and product c

i want to get product A , given ids of Product B and C.

How can i proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type::getParentIdsByChild` method for each of the products B and C and then check the intersection.

Let's say that B id is $idB and C id is $idC.

```
$typeInstance = Mage::getSingleton('bundle/product_type');
$bParents = $typeInstance->getParentIdsByChild($idB);
$cParents = $typeInstance->getParentIdsByChild($idC);
$intersection = array_intersect($bParents, $cParents);
```

All the ids in the `$intersection` array represent bundle products that have as child products both B and C.

Comment: it works but , i am bit confused if it will works in all cases and give right product ?

Comment: There could be cases when products B and C are part of 2 main products A and A1. Then you will get 2 ids in the `$intersection` array.

Comment: what if i restrict 
1: make a bundled product with not more than two products
2: what have i to do to make above filter apply to crtain category id :$typeInstance = Mage::getSingleton('bundle/product_type');

use this for for specific category not for all ?.

Comment: @saurav. This seams like a totally different question. and honestly I don't really understand it. Feel free to ask an other question and explain what you need.

Comment: i want to say if i make bundled products with only two product then we will always get right product ??

Comment: @saurav. It should. I see no reason why you won't get the right product. The only 'collision' case is the one I described above. If products B and C are part of 2 bundles. Both of them.